# Translate mssql trigger to mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I just migrated from mssql to mysql and i was using an insert trigger. Now i want to convert my mssql server trigger script to mysql. any help?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAutoInsert    
ON dbo.profile                        
AFTER INSERT                        
AS                        
DECLARE @var1 int ,@var2 int ,@var3 char (100) ,@var4 char (100) , @var5 char (3)     

select @var1 = profile_id, @var2 = profile_id, @var3 = fname , @var4 = fname ,@var5 = fpage     

From profile                      

BEGIN                        

IF @var5 = 'yes'    


INSERT INTO friends (req_id,resp_id,req_name,resp_name,fpage)                        
VALUES (@var1,@var2,@var3,@var4,'yes')
```

Comment: Your trigger doesn't make sense in SQL Server, unless `profile` has only one row.  And that would be quite unusual for a table.

Comment: it fires immediately after there's an insertion on the profile table

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAutoInsert AFTER INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE var1 INT;
    DECLARE var2 INT;
    DECLARE var3 CHAR(100);
    DECLARE var4 CHAR(100);
    DECLARE var5 CHAR(3);

    SELECT      profile_id,
                profile_id,
                fname,
                fname,
                fpage
        FROM    profile
        INTO    var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5;

    IF  var5 = 'yes'
    THEN

        INSERT INTO fiends
                (req_id, resp_id, req_name, resp_name, fpage)
            VALUES
                (var1, var2, var3, var4, 'yes');

    END IF;

END
```

Maybe this?